# Does "cottage industry" have a negative connotation?

Tags: phrase-usage

If I say that somebody's idea started a cottage industry of such-and-such, does it necessarily imply that I am criticizing them? Is the phrase itself demeaning?

Comment: No, there's nothing inherently wrong with cottage industries- http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cottage%20industry

Comment: Not at all. Please see a dictionary

Comment: This is one common definition: 
:  "an industry whose labor force consists of family units or individuals working at home with their own equipment". Does it have a negative connotation?...it all depends on context and the way you deal with this issue. Opinion-based in my view.

Comment: As @Josh61 said, it's context. If you wanted to be a mega-force, a world player, being described as a cottage industry would be an insult. If you wanted to emphasize your grass roots, it could be high praise.

Comment: Yes; you need an in-house perspective.